# Non constant solutions for Laplace Equation in polar coordinates depending on the angle

Tags: partial-differential-equations, harmonic-functions

In Evan's book is an example for finding radial solutions in polar coordinates. Now I'm searching for non constant solutions that satisfy the equation and depend only on $\varphi$.

$$\Delta_u = {\partial^2 u \over\partial r^2}+{1\over r}{\partial u\over\partial r}+{\partial^2 u \over\partial\varphi^2} =0$$

My guess is:
$$u=v(\varphi)=c\cdot\varphi$$
$$u_\varphi=c$$
$$u_{\varphi\varphi}=0$$

Is that correct?

Comment: That function is not continuous. What happens when $\varphi$ jumps at $2\pi$? You must require a boundary condition to your equation $\partial_\varphi^2 u=0$.

Comment: I see, it would be $v(2k\pi)=0$ for every $k\in\mathbb{N}$. How can I pick the boundary if I'm looking for solutions in the entire space $\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus\{0\}$?

Comment: That's not the right boundary condition. This is the right boundary condition: $v(0)=v(2\pi)$. In other words, you must require your function to be $2\pi$ periodic. I am afraid you are going to find trivial solutions only

Comment: How would it then be possible to proof that only trivial solutions exist? There are many $2\pi$ periodic functions but I can't find anyone with $\partial^2_\varphi u=0$.

Comment: Right, you can't. :-) Why is that? You can prove this by yourself. It is easy. Solve the equation $f''=0$.

Comment: Thank you for your hints. I integrated $u_{\varphi\varphi}=0$ twice to get $u=c_1\cdot\varphi+c_2$. Setting $u(0)=u(2\pi)$ follows $c_1=0$, hence $u(x)=c_2$ is constant.